# How to confirm the chosen radio button?

Tags: javascript

I have created three radio buttons. I want to run a function OnClick that ask the user to confirm the chosen radio button and tell what the checked radio button value is. Also if the user doesn't confirm the checked radio button, the radio button will be deselected.
This is code i have written but failed.

```
<input id="a1" type="radio" name="type" value="A1" onClick= "confirmation();" />A1
<input id="a2" type="radio" name="type" value="A2" onClick="confirmation();" />A2
<input id="a3" type="radio" name="type" value="A3" onClick="confirmation();"/>A3
```

Javascript

```
function confirmation() {


if (document.getElementById('a1').checked ) {
ty = document.getElementById('a1').value
var ask= confirm("You have chosen " + ty + " as your type \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok! " )

}
if (document.getElementById('a2').checked) {
level = document.getElementById('a2').value;
var ask= confirm("You have chosen " + ty + " as your Examination Level \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok! " )
}
if (document.getElementById('a3').checked) {
ty = document.getElementById('r1').value;
var ask= confirm("You have chosen " + ty + " as your type \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok! " )
}
    if (ask==true) {
        alert("You clicked ok");
    }
    if (ask==false) {
        alert("You clicked cancel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can sum it up to this:

```js
function confirmation(obj) {
    obj.checked ? confirm("You have chosen " + obj.value + " as your type \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok!") ? alert("You clicked ok") : obj.checked = false : "";
}
```

```html
<input id="a1" type="radio" name="type" value="A1" onClick="confirmation(this);" />A1
<input id="a2" type="radio" name="type" value="A2" onClick="confirmation(this);" />A2
<input id="a3" type="radio" name="type" value="A3" onClick="confirmation(this);" />A3
```

Pass `this` to the function. `this` refers to DOM object.

Comment: You need to uncheck it for cancel.

Comment: Great, it does what i want and it's way shorter. Also, why have you used obj.value

Comment: Is the value of the radio. `A1, A2` etc

Answer (score 3):

The function can be simpler. You don't have to check all the buttons because you can pass current one into function like `onclick="confirmation(this)"`. To uncheck radio button you would set `checked` property to `false`.

```js
function confirmation(radio) {

    var ask = confirm("You have chosen " + radio.value + " as your type \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok! ")
    
    if (ask) {
        alert("You clicked ok");
    }
    else {
        alert("You clicked cancel");
        radio.checked = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="a1" type="radio" name="type" value="A1" onclick="confirmation(this)" />A1
<input id="a2" type="radio" name="type" value="A2" onclick="confirmation(this)" />A2
<input id="a3" type="radio" name="type" value="A3" onclick="confirmation(this)" />A3
```

Comment: Only problem with this code is that you are firing your confirm box even if they UNCHECK the box.  You want to make sure it is checked, first.

Comment: @Stan, how can you uncheck a radio?

Comment: @Stan Not quite. Checking for checked is redundant because when click event fires we know for sure that this button is checked. We can't uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the radio buttons to clear them when cancelling the selection. You also had some small syntax errors in your code which are corrected below:

```
var ty;
function confirmation() {
    if (document.getElementById('a1').checked) {
        ty = document.getElementById('a1').value
        var ask = confirm("You have chosen " + ty + " as your type \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok! ")
    }
    if (document.getElementById('a2').checked) {
        ty = document.getElementById('a2').value;
        var ask = confirm("You have chosen " + ty + " as your Examination Level \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok! ")
    }
    if (document.getElementById('a3').checked) {
        ty = document.getElementById('a3').value;
        var ask = confirm("You have chosen " + ty + " as your type \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok! ")
    }
    if (ask == true) {
        alert("You clicked ok");
    }
    if (ask == false) {
        var elem = document.getElementsByName('type');
        for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) elem[i].checked = false;
        alert("You clicked cancel");
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/srpzfnhq/)**

Comment: You could have at least used else if to help improve the code. ;)

Comment: @epascarello - Else is waaay overrated ;)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use like so -**

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" onclick="return confirmation()" name="collections">
<input type="radio" value="2" onclick="return confirmation()" name="collections">
<input type="radio" value="3" onclick="return confirmation()" name="collections">



<script>
function confirmation(){
 if(confirm("Are you sure!"))
 {
  //do your job
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
```